# Extract data from a known string layout

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file called `example.txt`:

```
<data name="Jason" age="24">
<data name="Michelle" age="30">
<data name="Steve" age="41">
```

My goal is to extract the `name` and `age` from each of the data elements. My result should look something like this:

```
result = [('Jason', 24), ('Michelle', 30), ('Steve', 41)]
```

I assume I should use regular expressions to accomplish this task. Here's what I have so far but no luck:

```
import re

with open('example.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for d in data:
        pattern = re.compile(r'name="(\w)"')
        matches = pattern.finditer(d)
        for m in matches:
            print(m)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to check what `\w` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

r = re.compile('<data name="(.+)" age="([0-9]+)">')
results = []
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(r, line)
        results.append((match.group(1), match.group(2)))

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why not just:

```
import re
with open('example.txt') as f:
   l=[tuple(re.findall('".*"',i)[0].replace('"','').split(' age=')) for i in f]
```

List comprehension.

If you care about second element being a string, do an additional:

```
l=[(i[0],int(i[1])) for i in l]
```

And now after all:

```
print(l)
```

Is:

```
[('Jason', 24), ('Michelle', 30), ('Steve', 41)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two match groups, one for name, the other for age.
So your regex pattern should look like:

```
name=\"(\w+)\".*age=\"(\w+)\"
```

The group bracket `(\w+)` finds one or more word characters. In your case, this is applicable to both `name` and `age`.

Try this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'name=\"(\w+)\".*age=\"(\w+)\"')

for d in data:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, d)
    print(d)
    print(matches)
```

output:

```
<data name="Jason" age="24">
[('Jason', '24')]
 <data name="Michelle" age="30">
[('Michelle', '30')]
 <data name="Steve" age="41">
[('Steve', '41')]
```